# Exclude classes from a dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a project which depends on an artifact which is controlled by a supplier. This artifact contains some classes that I depend on, and some which are older and causing problems. Is there a way to get maven to automatically expand a jar, remove classes, and re-package them as a dependency? I'll try to give an example.

```
supplier:artifact:1.0.0
com.supplier.useful.ClassA
com.supplier.dto.ClassB (old)

us:dependency:1.1.20
com.supplier.dto.ClassB (new)

us:project-web:1.1.20
- supplier:artifact:1.0.0
- us:dependency:1.1.20
```

So - I need to use `ClassA` in project-web, but I need to use the `ClassB` from the `dependency` artifact. I can't modify supplier:artifact, or us:dependency.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since version 2.0.9 maven preserves the classpath ordering so if you define your patched classes in a jar BEFORE the supplier jar it will hide the supplier implementation.

Alternatively you can look at the [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) as it does exactly what you are asking according to me.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Maven 2.0.9+, then just put your class in a jar and declare it as dependency **before** the artifact from your supplier. As mentioned by @Peter, Maven uses the pom order for the classpath since Maven 2.0.9 (see [MNG-1412](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-1412) / [MNG-3111](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3111)).

If for whatever reason you're not satisfied with this solution, then you could use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to unpack the dependency in `target/classes` (which should be on the compile classpath) using [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) with some [`excludes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html#excludes) (see [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)). I wouldn't even try to repackage it, this will introduce useless complexity (replacing the old jar with the new one on the compile classpath won't be trivial, if feasible).