# Maven dependency: exclude one class

Tags: maven, dependencies

For example I have dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Can I exclude one class, for example `org/slf4j/Marker.class`?

Comment: `exclude` during what phase - compile or package?

Comment: package in .ear, using maven-ear-plugin

Comment: hmm! what you need in the .ear is the `slf4j-api.jar` without the specified class.  There is no straightforward way to achieve this.

Comment: slf4j-api is the example

Comment: But this does not make sense to exclude a single class in particular a class of an API. What you might do is to define the dependency scope to "provided" but this means it must be delivered by the environment where you deploy (JEE container based on EAr).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude classes from a dependency in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167118/exclude-classes-from-a-dependency-in-maven)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try it with the [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

Details on [why use shade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java) and [basic usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33880083/442256)

Answer (score 9):

Excluding a single class in not possible. Within `<dependency>` tags you can define `<exclusions/>`. However, these are for entire dependencies.

The shade plugin should be handled with care. Generally, it's not good practice to be creating a jar containing all your dependencies in one place as it tends to lead to problems if you are to be using the produced artifact in another project as a dependency. For example, shading slf4j in your jar and then depending on your artifact in another project where you have another slf4j will bring you grief.

Comment: like despot's  answer, replace it is possible

Comment: @Scott混合理论: Where in my answer have I mentioned that it isn't possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could change those classes and define them in a different jar/module which should be included as a dependency **before** the jar that supplies the dependency where your class to be excluded resides (Marker.class).

Maven remembers the classpath ordering from version 2.0.9.