# What is the maven-shade-plugin used for, and why would you want to relocate Java packages?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-shade-plugin

I found the maven-shade-plugin being used in someone's pom.xml. I've never used maven-shade-plugin before (and I'm a Maven n00b) so I tried to understand the reason for using this and what it does.

I looked at the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin), however I can't understand this statement:

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the packages of some of the dependencies.

The documentation on the page doesn't seem very newbie-friendly.

What is an "uber jar?" Why would someone want to make one? What's the point of renaming the packages of the dependencies? I tried to go through the examples on the maven-shade-plugin apache page such as "Selecting contents for Uber Jar," but I still can't understand what is being accomplished with "shading."

Any pointers to illustrative examples/use-cases (with an explanation of why shading was required in this case - what problem is it solving) would be appreciated. Lastly, when should I use the maven-shade-plugin?

Comment: For the naming "uber jar" I have the only association with German, where "über" means "over". Together literally it means "jar-over-all-other-jars". "Shading" is the same as "package reallocation" which is needed for classes or resources that collide.

Comment: `s/reallocation/relocation/` in the above comment.

Comment: The uber jar is just like the one ring: _One jar to rule them all, one jar to find them, One jar to bring them all and in the darkness bind them._

Comment: uber is a very misleading naming (confilict with 'Uber Technologies,Inc')

Comment: Now we just call it a **fat jar**

Answer (score 462, accepted):

Uber JAR, in short, is a JAR containing everything.

Normally in Maven, we rely on dependency management.  An artifact contains only the classes/resources of itself.  Maven will be responsible to find out all artifacts (JARs etc) that the project depending on when the project is built.

An uber-jar is something that takes all dependencies, and extracts the content of the dependencies and puts them with the classes/resources of the project itself, in one big JAR. By having such an uber-jar, it is easy for execution, because you will need only one big JAR instead of tons of small JARs to run your app.  It also eases distribution in some cases.

Just a side-note: avoid using uber-jar as a Maven dependency, as it is ruining the dependency resolution feature of Maven. Normally we create an uber-jar only for the final artifact for actual deployment or for manual distribution, but not for putting to Maven repository.

---

Update: I have just discovered I haven't answered one part of the question : "What's the point of renaming the packages of the dependencies?". Here are some brief updates that will hopefully help people having similar questions.

Creating an uber-jar for ease of deployment is one use case of the shade plugin. There are also other common use cases which involve package renaming.

For example, I am developing `Foo` library, which depends on a specific version (e.g. 1.0) of `Bar` library.  Assuming I cannot make use of other version of `Bar` lib (because API change, or other technical issues, etc).  If I simply declare `Bar:1.0` as `Foo`'s dependency in Maven, it is possible to fall into a problem:  A `Qux` project is depending on `Foo`, and also `Bar:2.0` (and it cannot use `Bar:1.0` because `Qux` needs to use new feature in `Bar:2.0`).  Here is the dilemma: should `Qux` use `Bar:1.0` (which `Qux`'s code will not work) or `Bar:2.0` (which `Foo`'s code will not work)?

In order to solve this problem, developer of `Foo` can choose to use shade plugin to rename its usage of `Bar`, so that all classes in `Bar:1.0` jar are embedded in `Foo` jar, and the package of the embedded `Bar` classes is changed from `com.bar` to `com.foo.bar`.  By doing so, `Qux` can safely depends on `Bar:2.0` because now `Foo` is no longer depending on `Bar`, and it is using its own copy of the "altered" `Bar` located in another package.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Is it called "shading" because it conceals the dependencies and other jars inside the uber-jar?

Comment: I am not really sure about the reason behind of name, but from its front page, it seems suggests the "shading" is describing the "hiding" of dependencies.  As you can optionally includes some dependencies in the shaded JAR, shade plugin will also generate a correct POM for you which remove the included dependencies.  It seems that shading is describing this process

Comment: @AdrianShum : Can you suggest how to create an uber jar, without using the shade plugin ? Or specifically how to resolve the "ruining of the dependency resolution feature of Maven" ?

Comment: @SurajMenon : Using Shade plugin is the easiest way to create uber-jar.  However, you can also use Assembly plugin, and use the built-in `jar-with-dependency` descriptor.  For problem of dependency roslution using uber-jar, I have already mentioned in my answer: Do not use uber-jar as dependency, period.  A bit more in detail: before you create the uber-jar, you should have a normal project with normal dependency.  That original artifact is the one you should use as dependency (instead of the uber-jar)

Comment: Just a minor question: Does it stop `Class.forName` from working?

Comment: @PEMapModder iirc, shade plugin does try to rename string literals according to package relocation.  So whether `Class.forName` works or not depends on how you construct the class name.  (I tried to find official feature description but cannot.  Got some hints of such feature from shade plugin issue tracker though)

Comment: https://product.hubspot.com/blog/the-fault-in-our-jars-why-we-stopped-building-fat-jars

Comment: For anyone looking for a sample github project that shows how to use the maven-shade-plugin, see the answer to this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833984/is-there-a-sample-project-in-github-that-shows-how-to-use-the-maven-shade-plugin

Answer (score 86):

I was wondering myself recently why elasticsearch shades and relocates a few (but not all) of its dependencies. Here's an explanation from the project's maintainer, **[@kimchy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275993/kimchy)**:

> The shading part is intentional, the shaded libraries we use in elasticsearch are for all intent and purpose part of elasticsearch, the version used is tied closely into what elasticsearch exposes and how it uses the library based on the internals of how the library works (and that changes between versions), netty and guava are great examples.
>
> Btw, I have no problem with actually providing several jars of elasticsearch, one with lucene not shaded, and one with Lucene shaded. Not sure how to do it with maven though. I don't want to provide a version that does not shade netty/jackson for example, because of the deep intimiate usage elasticsearch has with them (for example, using the upcoming bufferring improvement with any previous version of netty except for the current one will actually use more memory compared to using considerably less).

*-- https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2091#issuecomment-7156766*

And another here from **drewr**:

> The shading is important to keep our dependencies (notably netty, lucene, guava) close to our code so that we can fix an issue even if the upstream provider lags behind. It's possible we will distributed modularized versions of the code, which would help with your particular issue (#2091 for example), but we can't simply remove the shaded dependencies at this time. You can build a local version of ES for your purposes until there's a better solution.

*-- https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/3244#issuecomment-20125452*

So, that's one use case. As for an illustrative example, below is how maven-shade-plugin is used in elasticsearch's pom.xml (v0.90.5). The `artifactSet::include` lines instruct it what dependencies to pull into the uber JAR (basically, they are unzipped and and re-packaged alongside elasticsearch's own classes when the target elasticsearch jar is produced. (In case you didn't know this already, a JAR file is just a ZIP file that contains the program's classes, resources, etc., and some metadata. You can extract one to see how it's put together.)

The `relocations::relocation` lines are similar, except that in each case they also apply the specified substitutions to the dependency's classes - in this case, bringing them under `org.elasticsearch.common`.

Finally the `filters` section excludes some stuff from the target JAR that oughtn't be in there - such as JAR metadata, ant build files, text files, etc. that are packaged with some dependencies, but which don't belong in an uber JAR.

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
            <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                    <include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
                    <include>net.sf.trove4j:trove4j</include>
                    <include>org.mvel:mvel2</include>
                    <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</include>
                    <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile</include>
                    <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml</include>
                    <include>joda-time:joda-time</include>
                    <include>io.netty:netty</include>
                    <include>com.ning:compress-lzf</include>
                </includes>
            </artifactSet>
            <relocations>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>gnu.trove</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.trove</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>jsr166y</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166y</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>jsr166e</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.jsr166e</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>org.mvel2</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.mvel2</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.jackson</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>org.joda</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.joda</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>org.jboss.netty</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.netty</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>com.ning.compress</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>org.elasticsearch.common.compress</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
            </relocations>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/license/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                        <exclude>NOTICE</exclude>
                        <exclude>/*.txt</exclude>
                        <exclude>build.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: My hat is off to you Tom for providing this answer.  It brings a real-life example of how and why the maven-shade-plugin is used.  Finally, it makes sense!

Answer (score 8):

I think one example of the need for a "shaded" jar is an AWS Lambda function.  They seem to only let you upload 1 jar, not an entire collection of .jars like you would find in a typical .war file.  So, creating a single .jar with all of the project's dependencies lets you do this.

Comment: Use GraalVM to create a native image which AWS Lambda now supports. Startup times in the low ms :)

Answer (score 3):

---

### Small warning

Although that's not describe why one would like to use the maven-shade-plugin (since the selected answer describe it pretty well), I would like to note that I had problems with it. It changed the JAR (since that what it's doing) and it caused regression in my software.

So, instead of using this (or the maven-jarjar-plugin), I've used JarJar's binary which seems to work without a problem.

I'm posting here my solution since it took me some time to find a decent solution.

---

### Downlaod JarJar's JAR file

You can download the jar from here:
https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/
In the left menu you've got a link to download it.

---

### How to use JarJar in order to relocate classes of a JAR from one package to another

In this example we'll be changing the package from "com.fasterxml.jackson" to "io.kuku.dependencies.com.fasterxml.jackson".
- The source JAR is called "jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar" and new modified (target) JAR is called "kuku-jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar".
- The "jarjar" JAR file is in version 1.4

1. Create a "rules.txt" file.  The contents of the file should be (watch the period before the '@' character):
   rule com.fasterxml.jackson.** io.kuku.dependencies.com.fasterxml.jackson.@1
2. Run the following command:
   java -jar jarjar-1.4.jar process rules.txt jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar kuku-jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar

---

### Installing the modified JARs to the local repository

In this case I'm installing 3 files located on "c:\my-jars\"  folder.

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\my-jars\kuku-jackson-annotations-2.6.4.jar -DgroupId=io.kuku.dependencies -DartifactId=kuku-jackson-annotations -Dversion=2.6.4 -Dpackaging=jar

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\my-jars\kuku-jackson-core-2.6.4.jar -DgroupId=io.kuku.dependencies -DartifactId=kuku-jackson-core -Dversion=2.6.4 -Dpackaging=jar

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\my-jars\kuku-jackson-databind-2.6.4.jar -DgroupId=io.kuku.dependencies -DartifactId=kuku-jackson-annotations -Dversion=2.6.4 -Dpackaging=jar

---

### Using the modified JARs in the project's pom

In this example, this is the "dependencies" element in the projects pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <!-- kuku JARs -->
    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kuku.dependencies</groupId>
        <artifactId>kuku-jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kuku.dependencies</groupId>
        <artifactId>kuku-jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.kuku.dependencies</groupId>
        <artifactId>kuku-jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternate suggestion. This wasn't what I was looking for but turned out to be a much simpler and quicker solution for applying 1-time package translations on legacy libraries that will never change.

Comment: have you figure out the reason of such failures by comparing the content of their respective output?

Comment: Interesting and novel approach.  It helps solidify an understanding of just what the maven-shade-plugin is doing which is changing the byte code so that all `references` from classes in a package are changed to another package name.