# Alternate solution to the Maven Shade plugin in order to deploy a list of shared libraries in the Cargo plugin?

Tags: maven, libraries, shared, cargo

I need to execute non-regression tests on a system made of a set of Web Applications and shared libraries. I currently use the Maven Cargo plugin in order to deploy this system on an Apache Tomcat Web Container.

Up to now, the shared libraries, which are also used in the production environment, were referenced in a Maven BOM file, and then "imported" by other Maven projects. For instance, they are imported by the Maven projects that take care of the distribution of the software.

However, this approach does not work with the Cargo plugin, because this plugin seems not to support the import of the materials declared in a BOM file. As a workaround to this issue, I've used the Maven Shade plugin in order to produce an "uber" jar with all these shared libraries. This is working perfectly well, but I'm not 100% satisfied with this workaround, for the same reasons as those reported in [What is the maven-shade-plugin used for, and why would you want to relocate java packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for)

As there any other alternate approach to this issue (EAR not supported in our environment) ?