# Lightweight deployable WAR for a Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

A simple Spring Boot application which just prints a "Hello World" when packaged as an deploy-able WAR is 11.5 MB. When I exploded the WAR, the web-inf/lib folder was the root cause having too many libraries.

> 1. How to create the WAR with only the minimum necessary/dependent libraries ?
> 2. While mentioning ***provided*** as scope for ***spring-boot-starter-tomcat*** , does the embedded Tomcat Server still get packaged along with the WAR ?

I was playing around with the 'gs-spring-boot-complete' project that comes with the Spring Test Suite (STS) and here is the default POM that came with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <!-- ... -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- ... -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->
        <!-- tag::tests[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::tests[] -->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Update:
i removed the dependency on **spring-boot-starter-tomcat** and ***spring-boot-starter-actuator*** from the POM, still the WAR is 11.5 MB.

Currently there are only 2 direct dependencies ***spring-boot-starter-web*** & ***spring-boot-starter-test*** (i understand that this might in turn have other dependencies).

> My question is that, even if I am not going to have an embedded Tomcat
>   container, do "Spring Boot" applications generate such huge
>   deploy-able WARs ?  am trying to confirm if there is anything that
>   could be done to have an optimized (i mean small sized) deploy-able WAR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no interest in running your application as an executable war file and only want to deploy it to a servlet container then you can remove Spring Boot's Maven plugin and declare `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as a provided dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Remove Spring Boot's Maven plugin will prevent provided dependencies from being packaging in your war file. Making `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` a provided dependency, rather than excluding it altogether, will allow you to run integration tests using embedded Tomcat.

This will give you a war file that's 7.6MB. Depending on your application and the technologies that you want to use, you may also want to consider excluding some of `spring-boot-starter-web`'s transitive dependencies. For example, it's pulling in Hibernate Validator (> 0.5MB) and Jackson (> 1MB).

Comment: that's great... even-though i don't want to do this right away, i was curious to know the best practices being followed around. Even before not wanting to bloat my WAR file unnecessarily , I wanted to understand what was really going on and what else could be done. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The intention is to create a war/jar with all your dependencies included. What is the minimum you want to deploy?

Id suggest removing the tomcat and actuator dependency for a start - then recheck the size

Comment: i removed the dependency on spring-boot-starter-tomcat and spring-boot-starter-actuator from the POM, still the WAR is 11.5 MB. Currently there are only 2 direct dependencies spring-boot-starter-web & spring-boot-starter-test (i understand that this might in turn have other dependencies).  My question is that, even if I am not going to have an embeded Tomcat container, do "Spring Boot" applications generate such huge deploy-able WARs ?  am trying to confirm if there is anything that could be done to have an optimized deploy-able WAR.

Comment: Just reading this link - http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/ - you have to declare the embedded preferences as provided to remove tomcat

Comment: yes, you can notice the pom content i've pasted. It is declared as "provided" in my POM

Comment: Oh I see - ive read you can use a shade plugin with maven. That might help reduce the size

Comment: just in-case for my reference, here is a good explanation on the maven shade plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java

Comment: The shade plugin cannot possibly help I'm afraid. If you don't want the embedded tomcat, exclude it (don't make it provided), and remove the spring-boot-maven-plugin (that's the one that does the "shading").