# Shade (relocate) one version of a transitive dependency, but not the other

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I've got a Maven project that contains two dependencies, *A* and *B*. Each of these depends transitively on *C*, but they depend on different versions of *C*. Let's say that *A* depends on *C* version 1, and *B* depends on *C* version 2.

Unfortunately, *A* is not bytecode-compatible with version 2, nor *B* with version 1. (As it happens, *A* is *source-compatible* with version 2, but I don't think that will help us here.)

This means that I need both versions of the transitive dependency in my project, and I need *A* to use version 1, and *B* to use version 2.

Is there a way of doing this?

I had assumed that I would need to use the shade plugin to relocate the package name of *A* and all its dependencies, but this doesn't seem to be possible. If I shade *A*, its dependencies don't get shaded, and it still picks up version 2, and fails to run.

Comment: I dont think that its possible because jdk is going to just load one version not both.

Comment: You could take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java?rq=1
The first answer states that it's possible. The second answer provides some example that could be useful to you.

Comment: 2 year old question. Still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Create another project wrapper `A` named `A-wrapper`. Relocate `C` in `A-wrapper`.
Then in your main project, depends on `A-wrapper` and `B`.

I've met a similar problem on pb2 and pb3 and it is resolved using this way.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41394239/1395722

Answer (score -1):

Assuming dependency **A requires v1 of C** and dependency **B requires v2 of C**. You can create an uber jar of A containing v1 of C but changing the packaging using shade plugin,
Example jar A has contents of C with new packaging **"v1.c.something"**. Do the same for B, so jar B has contents of C with new packaging **"v2.c.something"**. You need to include only the conflicting dependencies not all.

Comment: The questioner's point is that both A and B are not in your control to simply shade the dependency C.