# use protobuf3 with some lib which depends on protobuf2 in Java

Tags: java, gradle, hbase, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf3 to represent our data, while we need hbase to store the data, it seems like hbase depends on protobuf2.

When i write the following line to create our hbase table

```
admin.createTable(desc);
```

then I got an Excepiton: `NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/LiteralByteString`

I've tried using [gradle's shadow plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) to relocate com.google.protobuf to shadow.google.com, then it throw a similar message `NoClassDefFoundError: shadow/google/protobuf/LiteralByteString`.

Comment: if you'll manage how to fix it, write the answer please

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I've posted my answer. If it make any help, feel free to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a sub-project, and name it 'hbase-wrapper'
2. Move the dependencies for hbase to the new project
3. Shadow protobuf in the new project
4. Add dependency to the sub-project on the main project

Here's some snip code

```
// part of build.gradle of the sub-project
...
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-client', version: '1.2.4'
}

shadowJar {
    relocate('com.google.protobuf', 'hbasesaver.google.protobuf')
}

// part of build.gradle for main project
...
compile project(path: ':hbase-wrapper', configuration: 'shadow')
```