# How to use maven shade to build jar and war

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I'm on a project working with openrdf, and I require the shade plugin to transform my service entries. I would like to build a war and a jar simultaneously, as both usages are possible. However, I cannot get the shade plugin to produce a shaded jar and a shaded war at the same time - shade only invokes on the package type defined in the properties, and binding e.g. the jar plugin to the package phase in order to create a jar next to the war results in an unshaded jar. How can I create both a shaded jar and a shaded war at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maven-shade-plugin used for, and why would you want to relocate java packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If by "shaded war" you mean just the regular war with all dependencies packed into `WEB-INF/lib`, then you might just use `maven-war-plugin` separately and use `jar` as packaging type. This way shade plugin will work correctly. And `.war`  will be built by plugin.

Below is pom.xml. And [here](https://github.com/Fantast/stackoverflow-test2) is working example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>so.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackoverflow-test2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-fatjar</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: I have the same configuration. Locally i indeed obtain WAR + shadded JAR when i run mvn package, but for some reason the WAR is not deployed. Should the WAR be somehow explicitely declared to get deployed?