# can I import both Jersey 1 and Jersey 2 and use different imports in different classes?

Tags: java, rest, gradle, jersey

I want to send a Pojo with a POST using jersey.

I understand there are 2 versions of Jersey: 1... and 2...

I'm adding code to an existing project which uses:

```
compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.19')
compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19')
compile group:  'org.codehaus.jackson', name:'jackson-jaxrs', version: '1.1.1'
```

can I add the path to `jersey 2..` as well and import the right classes whenever I need them in my classes?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, they will conflict.
If you have specific (and well defined) usage of Jersey2 modules you can perhaps consider shading it (or Jersey1 or Both) - that way they would not conflict, but I recommend choosing 1 version if possible (probably Jersey2) and using it, since it has a lot of improvements and bugfixes over version 1 and will remove the conflict issues.

Here is a nice answer in SO that [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java/13620420#13620420) what shading is