# How to create a .jar out of multiple jars using Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I have a project which has multiple .jar files in it. To add this as a dependency, I need to turn all these jars into one big jar. So far I have come until:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>mainProjects</groupId>
      <artifactId>mainProjects.master</artifactId>
      <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>mainProjects</groupId>
   <artifactId>sampleModule1</artifactId>
   <name>sampleModule1</name>
   <version>1.0.0.qualifier</version>
   <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>Sample1.jar</include>
                        <include>Sample2.jar</include>
                     </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-final</finalName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.artifactId}/build</outputDirectory>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

This creates the final jar, however, inside there are no content from the other jars (sample1.jar and sample2.jar) as there should be. I have looked into the documentation of the plugin, however all they did was to do it via class files, not jars. So I don't know how to proceed from now on.

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

So in order to make it clear, hereby I share the project structure that I have:

```
 +- mainProjects
 |   +- pom.xml
 |   +- mainProject1
 |   |  +- pom.xml
 |   |  +- src
 |   +- mainProject2 
 |   |  +- pom.xml
 |   |  +- src   
 |   +- group1
 |   |  +- pom.xml  
 |   |  +- sampleModule1
 |   |  | +- pom.xml  
 |   |  | +- build
 |   |  | +- sample1.jar
 |   |  | +- sample2.jar
 |   |  | +- sample3.jar
 |   |  | +- sample4.jar
 |   |  | +- sample5.jar
 |   |  | +- sample6.jar
 |   |  +- sampleModule2
 |   |  | +- pom.xml
 |   |  | +- src
```

Now, I want to be able to use `sampleModule1` as a dependency in the `pom.xml` of `mainProject1` as a jar, like this:

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>group1</groupId>
         <artifactId>sampleModule1</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.qualifier</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>sampleModule1/build/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-final.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
```

to achieve this, I need to compile all the jars into one jar, so that I can add it by using one `systemPath`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386712/6533075) which shows an example of how to include multiple files into one. However, in the example they are not jars, but rather classes and others. Now here, I am trying to achieve the same, but with only jars.

Comment: what is your project structure? are these jar files outside pom.xml file?

Comment: Ah thanks for reminding. They are in the same directory with the pom.xml.

Comment: why dont you add them as dependencies in pom.xml? that's the meaning of maven!

Comment: 10 .jars under the same project, are you sure? I mean, as far as I know while adding dependency, you are allowed to add one .jar per artifact-id. Can I just use the same artifact-id and keep adding all the jars?

Comment: please post a screenshot of your structure and your actual jar files to help us better understand. thnx!

Comment: @Apostolos Done, kindly check the question again. Thanks!

Comment: You have been told a few times during the past two days to _not_ use `<scope>system/<systemPath>`. Why are you still ignoring these advices? What are these `sampleX.jar`s good for? There is a `build.xml`. Are you migrating from Ant/Ivy? If yes, I strongly recommend to abandon this Ant/Ivy approach of copying dependency artifacts into each and every project. Otherwise you are more working against Maven rather than with it. Have you already read the docs I linked you recently?

Comment: i agree. scope system should not be used. install these jars in local repo if needed and reference them inside your pom.xml not as relative system paths.

Comment: I have 3 issues regarding maven and this is one of them. I didn't know that `system` shouldn't have been used **at all in any case**. Now that you told me for this as well, point taken. Now, is my problem here related to `systemPath` issue?  Nevertheless, yes I am migrating from Ant to maven. I read the first link (repositories) and the second link is a  complete book, which I cannot read in such a short time.

Comment: @Apostolos I cannot use terminal commands as the project is supposed to work on a Jenkins machine on-the-fly, so using that `install` command and installing these jars are out of the option. The question stands: is there a way of creating one jar out of multiple jars? That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem! If you just want to to add files into your jar, you can use the `resources` tags to add them

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>lib</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This now puts all jar files from you `lib` folder into the main jar. The root folder is the folder from which you invoked the corresponding `pom.xml`. With this you can add arbitrary files to you jar.  For a [complete syntax reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) take a look here.

The other way and maybe the most convenient way is to use the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) this allows you to copy almost everything into you final jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.3</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <artifactSet>
               <includes>
                  <include>groupid:artifactid_a</include>
                  <include>groupid:artifactid_b</include>
               </includes>
            </artifactSet>
            <filters>
               <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <includes>
                     <include>resources/*.png</include>
                  </includes>
               </filter>
            </filters>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `artifactSet` parts allow you to reference jar from within you local repro to be included just by mentioning their `groupid` and `artifactid`

This will include the content like `class` files, `manifest` etc. and also the folder structure) of the mentioned artifact (from you local repro) into you jar.

If you want to include other arbitrary files into you jar you can use the `filter` tag of the plugin which allows you to specify files and file-patterns directly. For a [complete syntax reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) take a look here.

P.S.: If you want to exclude certain files you can replace the `include` tag by an `exclude` tag ;-)