# Best solution for version conflict in Spark program

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, version-control

I have a Spark program which requires several dependencies.

One dependency: a.jar is version of 2.8 on the cluster `a_2.8.jar`, however, I need to use its version 2.9, `a_2.9.jar`.

Everytime I launch the program, the spark will automatically load a_2.8.jar from the cluster, instead of load `a_2.9.jar`, even I have submitted this jar by `--jars a_2.9.jar`.

I tried to use `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` setting, but there is another problem. There is a "secret" jar file, say "`b.jar`", in my userClassPath that doesn't works with the cluster, and there are so many dependencies, I don't know which jar doesn't works.

To sum up:

If I use cluster default class path, `a.jar` will conflict.

If I use `userClassPathFirst`, `b.jar` will conflict. ( I don't know which b.jar)

I wish someone could advise me, what is the best solution here, to minimize the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uber Jar` creation by using `shade plugin` can be your solution. `Uber jar` is collecting all the dependent jars in your packaged jar so that we don't have conflict. We can relocate/rename a conflicting jar with `shade plugin`. There are more advantages. More information can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is IMO to:

Get the dependency tree with your package manager or any other tool you want use. For example in maven you could use `mvn dependency:tree` [see here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) to double check which dependencies could potentially cause the class path errors and remove them by excluding them in your build file definition like [it is pointed out here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Then, rebuilding your JAR and try it again.