# scalap and javap showing different method signature

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark, jvm

I am facing very weird issue, i am having a maven dependency in my project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the class `org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI` which i am using from this dependency, and it has one method with below signature

```
def getHandlers : scala.Seq[org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler] = { /* compiled code */ }
```

but when i am executing my program, its failing with exception **`NoSuchMethodError`**.

So i started little digging it. when i decompile my jar with **scalap** its shows me above signature, but when i decompile with **javap** option, it shows different.

```
public scala.collection.Seq<org.spark_project.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler> getHandlers();
```

Comment: can u post the output for both? and what arguments have you invoked `javap` with?

Comment: @Eugene, this is the command for scala
`scalap -classpath .m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.11\2.0.0\spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI`
And this is for java 

`javap -classpath .m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.11\2.0.0\spark-core_2.11-2.0.0.jar org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI`

Answer (score 0):

`scala.Seq` is a type alias for `scala.collection.Seq` (this [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591709/cats-auto-derived-with-seq) in Scala 2.13)

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.12/src/library/scala/package.scala#L45

```
type Seq[+A] = scala.collection.Seq[A]
```

`org.spark_project.jetty` is instead of `org.eclipse.jetty` because of shading

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/pom.xml#L2239-L2285

```
    <!-- Package to use when relocating shaded classes. -->
    <spark.shade.packageName>org.spark_project</spark.shade.packageName>
    ...

      <!--
        The shade plug-in is used here to create effective pom's (see SPARK-3812), and also
        remove references from the shaded libraries from artifacts published by Spark.
      -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
          <artifactSet>
            <includes>
              <include>org.spark-project.spark:unused</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util</include>
              <include>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server</include>
              <include>com.google.guava:guava</include>
            </includes>
          </artifactSet>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>org.eclipse.jetty</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.jetty</shadedPattern>
              <includes>
                <include>org.eclipse.jetty.**</include>
              </includes>
            </relocation>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>${spark.shade.packageName}.guava</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

[What is an uber jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar)

[What is a shaded jar? And what is the difference/similarities between uber jar and shaded jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810578/what-is-a-shaded-jar-and-what-is-the-difference-similarities-between-uber-jar-a)

[What is the maven-shade-plugin used for, and why would you want to relocate Java packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java)

[How maven shading works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802487/how-maven-shading-works)

[How the class loader works in Java with a shaded jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74538843/how-the-class-loader-works-in-java-with-a-shaded-jar)

---

Here is one more case where `scalap` and `javap` outputs differ

[Run a scala code jar appear NoSuchMethodError:scala.Predef$.refArrayOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops)

```
scala-2.13.10/bin/scalap -cp scala-2.13.10/lib/scala-library.jar scala.Predef$
```

`def refArrayOps(scala.Array[scala.Any]): scala.Any`

```
jdk-17.0.5/bin/javap -cp scala-2.13.10/lib/scala-library.jar scala.Predef$
```

`public <T> T[] refArrayOps(T[])`

`javap` shows the return type of `refArrayOps` as `T[]` i.e. `Array[T]` or `Array[Any]` while `scalap` shows just `Any`. This is because of `@inline` and `AnyVal`

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L464

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.10/src/library/scala/collection/ArrayOps.scala#L197

```
@inline implicit def refArrayOps[T <: AnyRef](xs: Array[T]): ArrayOps[T] = new ArrayOps(xs)

final class ArrayOps[A](private val xs: Array[A]) extends AnyVal { ... }
```

`@inline` https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.10/scala/inline.html

`extends AnyVal` https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html