# Hikari NoSuchMethodError on AWS EMR/Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, hikaricp

I am trying to upgrade `EMR` from `5.13`to `5.35` using `spark-2.4.8`. The jar I'm trying to use has a dependency on `HikariCP:4.0.3` which is called to set the db pool-config `setKeepaliveTime`. While I can run my job fine on my local machine, it bombs out in `EMR-5.35` with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(J)
```

The problem is, in runtime, the `HikariConfig` is being loaded from `file:/usr/lib/spark/jars/HikariCP-java7-2.4.12.jar`  instead of what was provided as a dependency in my custom/fat jar. The workaround right now is to remove that jar, but is there an elegant way to know where that jar is coming from just on the EMR and how could we remove that on start-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, anyone else faces this, the fix was [shading](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) (Process that allows renaming packages on the Uber jar), I basically had to make sure the dependency I use doesn't get overridden with the one that's stale in `EMR-5.35.0`. It looked something like the below:

```
assembly / assemblyShadeRules := Seq(
  ShadeRule
    .rename("com.zaxxer.hikari.**" -> "x_hikari_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("x" % "y" % z)
    .inProject
  )
```

And that was pretty much it, after the above lines were put in and the new jar was created, it worked like a charm.

More on shading can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49811665)