# Closure Compiler - Protobuf vulnerability

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-closure-compiler, protobuf-java

We are using Java 8 and the max tag of closure compiler that supports Java 8 is v20220502,
Now the protobuf-java version used in this tag is **3.17.0**. that is mention is **protobuf_proto_rules** in **WORKSPACE.bazel**

```
http_archive(
    name = "protobuf_proto_rules",
    # output from `sha256sum` on the downloaded tar.gz file
    sha256 = "66bfdf8782796239d3875d37e7de19b1d94301e8972b3cbd2446b332429b4df1",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-4.0.0",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/4.0.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/4.0.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)
```

We want to use protobuf_java version from https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/blob/5.3.0-21.7/proto/private/dependencies.bzl **3.21.7** so we edited **WORKSPACE.bazel** like this

```
http_archive(
    name = "protobuf_proto_rules",
    sha256 = "dc3fb206a2cb3441b485eb1e423165b231235a1ea9b031b4433cf7bc1fa460dd",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-5.3.0-21.7",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/5.3.0-21.7.tar.gz",
    ],
)
```

getting the following error after this

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/.../_bazel_.../7eswowuu/external/rules_cc/cc/private/rules_impl/cc_flags_supplier.bzl", line 16, column 76, in <toplevel>
                load("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_utils.bzl", "find_cpp_toolchain", "use_cpp_toolchain")
Error: file '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_utils.bzl' does not contain symbol 'use_cpp_toolchain' (did you mean 'find_cpp_toolchain'?)
ERROR: While resolving toolchains for target //:compiler_unshaded: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp': in C:/users/.../_bazel_.../7eswowuu/external/rules_cc/cc/defs.bzl: Extension file 'cc/private/rules_impl/cc_flags_supplier.bzl' has errors
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:compiler_unshaded_deploy.jar' failed; build aborted: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '@bazel_tools//tools/cpp': in C:/users/.../_bazel_.../7eswowuu/external/rules_cc/cc/defs.bzl: Extension file 'cc/private/rules_impl/cc_flags_supplier.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.810s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

How to upgrade protobuf_java version to 3.21.7

Answer (score 0):

We have added the new protobuf rules in the beginning of the WORKSPACE.bazel and it resolved the issue for use. here is the file we used with v20220502

```
workspace(name = "com_google_javascript_jscomp")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG = "4.2"
RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA = "cd1a77b7b02e8e008439ca76fd34f5b07aecb8c752961f9640dea15e9e5ba1ca"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-%s" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
    sha256 = RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_SHA,
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/%s.zip" % RULES_JVM_EXTERNAL_TAG,
)

#
# To update google_bazel_common, locate the git commit to depend on and
# use something like the following to determine the sha256
#  curl -L https://github.com/google/bazel-common/archive/<git-commit-id>.zip |
#  sha256
#
#

http_archive(
     name = "protobuf_proto_rules",
    sha256 = "dc3fb206a2cb3441b485eb1e423165b231235a1ea9b031b4433cf7bc1fa460dd",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-5.3.0-21.7",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/5.3.0-21.7.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@protobuf_proto_rules//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()

http_archive(
    name = "google_bazel_common",
    # output from `sha256sum` on the downloaded zip file
    sha256 = "cb37c4977b01311f72157897b1b180b6caf2fc88336ee64b39152af61f8708a9",
    strip_prefix = "bazel-common-82a7dd0f4cd8593fdaa40d65a1fa820b14ff3493",
    urls = [
      "https://github.com/google/bazel-common/archive/82a7dd0f4cd8593fdaa40d65a1fa820b14ff3493.zip",
    ],
)

load("@google_bazel_common//:workspace_defs.bzl", "google_common_workspace_rules", "maven_import")

google_common_workspace_rules()

maven_import(
    # http://args4j.kohsuke.org/index.html
    group_id = "args4j",
    artifact_id = "args4j",
    version = "2.33",
    sha256 = "91ddeaba0b24adce72291c618c00bbdce1c884755f6c4dba9c5c46e871c69ed6",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)

maven_import(
    # https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils
    group_id = "io.github.java-diff-utils",
    artifact_id = "java-diff-utils",
    version = "4.0",
    sha256 = "810232374e76a954949f0e2185cd7d9515addb918cf3da3481f77e07c356b49a",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)

maven_import(
    # https://github.com/google/gson
    group_id = "com.google.code.gson",
    artifact_id = "gson",
    version = "2.9.0",
    sha256 = "c96d60551331a196dac54b745aa642cd078ef89b6f267146b705f2c2cbef052d",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)

maven_import(
    # https://github.com/google/re2j
    group_id ="com.google.re2j",
    artifact_id = "re2j",
    version ="1.3",
    sha256 = "d8040fa1c54c1ce208199015b6e599ec2ef37b7780f8f55a8b4b4b4299bade19",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)

maven_import(
    # https://ant.apache.org/
    group_id ="org.apache.ant",
    artifact_id = "ant",
    version ="1.10.12",
    sha256 = "5c6a438c3ebe7a306eba452b09fa307b0e60314926177920bca896c4a504eaf6",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)

maven_import(
    # https://truth.dev/protobufs
    group_id = "com.google.truth.extensions",
    artifact_id = "truth-liteproto-extension",
    version = "1.1",
    sha256 = "f637de4743194a870316a55a1c50c89638355a2323d96b6ced363a22d6ced316",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)

maven_import(
    # https://truth.dev/protobufs
    group_id = "com.google.truth.extensions",
    artifact_id = "truth-proto-extension",
    version = "1.1",
    sha256 = "d2fa8736dcb541813f8f4090ecc0d634b85cb82bd6d486f1af975458d0238afe",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)

maven_import(
    # https://github.com/google/jimfs
    group_id = "com.google.jimfs",
    artifact_id = "jimfs",
    version = "1.2",
    sha256 = "de16d5c8489729a8512f1a02fbd81f58f89249b72066987da4cc5c87ecb9f72d",
    licenses = ["notice"],
)



http_archive(
    name = "protobuf_java_rules",
    sha256 = "7c4bbe11e41c61212a5cf16d9aafaddade3f5b1b6c8bf94270d78215fafd4007",
    strip_prefix = "rules_java-c13e3ead84afb95f81fbddfade2749d8ba7cb77f",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_java/archive/c13e3ead84afb95f81fbddfade2749d8ba7cb77f.tar.gz",  # 2021-01-25
)

load("@protobuf_java_rules//java:repositories.bzl", "remote_jdk8_repos")

remote_jdk8_repos()

# Jarjar is a Google tool (https://github.com/google/jarjar) for generating
# shaded JARs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810578). This repo contains
# Bazel bindings for Jarjar, under the Apache license.
http_archive(
    name = "com_github_johnynek_bazel_jar_jar",
    # output from `sha256sum` on the downloaded zip file
    sha256 = "fdf2c5276e5c6f27efa1e0b64a301f5a122d84a4c1c0dd80006dbbc530a16773",
    strip_prefix = "bazel_jar_jar-171f268569384c57c19474b04aebe574d85fde0d",
    urls = [
      "https://github.com/johnynek/bazel_jar_jar/archive/171f268569384c57c19474b04aebe574d85fde0d.zip",
    ],
)

load("@com_github_johnynek_bazel_jar_jar//:jar_jar.bzl", "jar_jar_repositories")

jar_jar_repositories()
```