# How to configure Maven POM file for a JavaFX project if deploying to a JVM bundled with JavaFX/OpenJFX technology?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

At least a couple of vendors provide editions of their JDK/JRE products that bundle the *OpenJFX* implementation of *JavaFX* technology. Namely, *Azul Systems* and *BellSoft*.

If deploying a [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) app to users’ machines where a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) bundled with JavaFX technology has already been installed, how do I write the dependencies and executions portions of the Maven POM driving my build?

### Dependencies

Do I want to *not* bundle any [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) libraries with my app, if I know a JVM bundled with OpenJFX is present?

If so, how do I write the POM to make the OpenJFX libraries available to me while developing but not include them in my final JAR file?

Currently I have this given to me by the [JavaFX project template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) provided by [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA):

```xml
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
…
```

### Executions of `javafx-maven-plugin`

How do I configure the `executions` element of my `javafx-maven-plugin` element in the POM if I want to build just a JAR without any bundling of a JVM or native image?

Right now I have the following, given by the JavaFX project template provided by IntelliJ:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>work.basil.voters.voters_wa/work.basil.voters.voters_wa.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                <launcher>app</launcher>
                <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

Below is the entire POM.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.voters</groupId>
    <artifactId>voters_wa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Voters WA</name>
    <description>Parses Washington State voter registration data, then providing access via queries and reporting. For political purposes only. Commercial use of that data is prohibited by law.</description>
    <inceptionYear>2023</inceptionYear>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.plugin.validation>VERBOSE</maven.plugin.validation>
    </properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>20.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>work.basil.voters.voters_wa/work.basil.voters.voters_wa.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                <launcher>app</launcher>
                <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: "_Do I want to not bundle any OpenJFX libraries with my app, if I know a JVM bundled with OpenJFX is present?_"  – Correct. If JavaFX is going to be provided by the client's installation of Java, then you should not include JavaFX in your application. "_If so, how do I write the POM to make the OpenJFX libraries available to me while developing but not include them in my final JAR file?_" – Does using `<scope>provided</scope>` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short guide to using Maven to work with JDKs and runtimes that already include JavaFX:

- Azul Zulu "JDK FX" and "JRE FX".
- BellSoft Liberica "Full JDK" or "Full JRE".

##### Development

For development you have these choices:

1. Include the JavaFX maven dependencies in your pom.xml and work with a JDK that does not include JavaFX.
2. Include the JavaFX maven dependencies in your pom.xml and work with a JDK that includes JavaFX.
3. Don't place the JavaFX maven dependencies in your pom.xml and work with a JDK that includes JavaFX.
4. Include the JavaFX maven dependencies in your pom.xml as a [`provided` scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26975818/642706) and work with a JDK that includes JavaFX.

| Development scenario | JavaFX dependencies included in POM | JDK bundled with OpenJFX | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # 1 | ✅ |  | More portable for sharing with developers |
| # 2 | ✅ | ✅ |  |
| # 3 |  | ✅ |  |
| # 4 | ✅ `<scope>provided</scope>` | ✅ | • Leanest option for when all developers *and* all users have installed appropriate JDK/JRE with JavaFX • Also for non-modular app in shaded JAR |

Any of the options will work.

Option 1 is probably the most portable if you share the project with other developers.  Then the developers won't have to be extra careful to find and use a JDK that includes JavaFX (which is rarer than ones that don't have JavaFX).

Option 4 is probably best if you know that all developers will be using an appropriate JDK that includes JavaFX or if your target is to build a non-modular [shaded jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810578/what-is-a-shaded-jar-file-and-what-is-the-difference-similarities-between-an-ub) for the application. By using scope `provided`, your final app artifact will lack the OpenJFX libraries thereby producing a smaller size.

##### Distribution

For distribution, you don't need to include the JavaFX maven jars, because you know your target platform will have those.

When you build your app, by default, it will create a jar file for the application.  And that jar file will not include the dependent code.  This is the default execution of the [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), which is implicitly included with the maven distribution, so you don't need any configuration to use it in its default mode.

Even though you don't need the JavaFX modules as dependencies, you do need any other dependencies your app requires.  If it is a simple app with no other dependencies, then you don't need to worry about this.  But if it is not a simple app, then you need to a way to include those dependencies.

If it is a [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) app, you can create a zip of the dependent jars, your app jar and an execution script.  The job of the execution script is to find the Java command and use it to run your application with the dependent modules on the module path.

This can be done using the [maven-assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), which can be configured to:

1. Copy your application jar to an assembly directory.
2. Copy your application dependencies (excluding JavaFX dependencies) to the assembly directory.
3. Copy the execution script to the assembly directory.
4. Create the zip file for the distribution.

If you do include the JavaFX maven jars in the assembly, it will probably still work if it is a modular app, it is just not necessary in your case.  They can be excluded either by not having them as dependencies in the project to start with, or if they are there, then in the assembly definition, filtering them out ([by filtering out all dependencies from the `org.openjfx` group id](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html)).

If it is a non-modular application, you can use the [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), to shade your application code and all of the code from the dependent libraries into a single jar file.  If you use this option, then don't put dependencies on the JavaFX Maven artifacts in your project file (or use provided scope for them), because you don't want to shade the JavaFX code into your jar file, it will only create confusion when the underlying platform already makes JavaFX available.  In such a case, you should do your development using a JDK which includes JavaFX.

##### Provided scope

If desired, the scope [provided](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) can be set for the JavaFX jars to indicate that they don't need to be bundled as runtime dependencies for the application because they are already part of the target platform, yet are still available at development and build time, so that you can compile against them.

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

When provided scope is set, by default, tasks that function based on dependencies such as shading or assembly copying tasks, won't also copy the provided dependencies, because the tasks know they won't be needed.

The use of provided scope for JavaFX dependencies in this case for targeting runtimes which already include JavaFX is similar to the use of provided scope on servlet API dependencies in web development when targeting a web application server that includes the Java servlet API.

##### FAQ

> How do I configure the executions element of my javafx-maven-plugin element in the POM if I want to build just a JAR without any bundling of a JVM or native image?

You don't.  If you aren't building a native image using jlink via the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin), then there is no need to use it, you can delete it from the project.

Aside from the linking function, the *javafx-maven-plugin* also has the ability to launch a JavaFX application. I don't use that, and rely on my IDE execution ability to run my application. But if you were in the habit of using the `javax:run` target of the *javafx-maven-plugin*, you could keep the plugin around for that.

Comment: Would use of `<scope>provided</scope>` be a legitimate Option # 4 on your list of development scenarios?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Please verify (a) my edits to the text of your development scenario # 4, and (b) the correctness of the summary table of development scenarios I added to your helpful Answer. (I had really botched up my edits, but I think I got it straight now.)

Comment: @BasilBourque changes look good, thx for adding the table, it's clearer.