# scala: Nested String Map Builder

Tags: scala, dictionary, generics, collections

I want to create a class called NestedStrMap where it has a signature as such:

```
   final class NestedStrMap[A](list: List[A], first: A => String, rest: (A => String)*)
```

I want to write a function `asMap` inside of it where I can take `first` and `rest` to build a nested map. However, I can't figure out how to define the return type of this function.

```
  def asMap = {
    rest.toList.foldLeft(list.groupBy(first)) { (acc, i) =>
      acc.view.mapValues(l => l.groupBy(i)).toMap  // fails because the return type doesn't match
    }
  }
```

Here's an example of how I'd like to use it:

```
   case class TestResult(name: String, testType: String, score: Int)
   
   val testList = List(
     TestResult("A", "math", 75),
     TestResult("B", "math", 80),
     TestResult("B", "bio", 90),
     TestResult("C", "history", 50)
   )
   val nestedMap = NestedStrMap(testList, _.name, _.testType)
   val someMap: Map[String, Map[String, List[TestResult]] = nestedMap.asMap

   println(someMap)
   /*
     Map(
       "A" -> Map("math" -> List(TestResult("A", "math", 75)))
       "B" -> Map(
         "math" -> List(TestResult("B", "math", 80)),
         "bio" -> List(TestResult("B", "bio", 90))
       ),
       "C" -> Map("history" -> List(TestResult("C", "history", 50)))  
     )
    */
```

Is this doable in scala?

Comment: This is doable, I can think of three possible solutions. - 1. Define your own ADT to represent nested maps, it would be very vanilla but will lose some type safety _(similar to how one would define a `Json` data type)_. - 2. Write an **sbt** source generator to implement each overload _(up to some arbitrary number like `22`)_, that way the type safety will be preserved. - 3. use **Shapeless** _(or something similar like **Magnolia** or macros)_ to write a generic version that computes the appropriate type at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to return `Map[String, Map[String, ... Map[String, List[A]]]]`. The type must be known at compile time. So the length of `rest: (A => String)*` must be known at compile time. You can introduce a type class using Shapeless [Sized](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#collections-with-statically-known-sizes)

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
import shapeless.nat.{_0, _2}
import shapeless.{Nat, Sized, Succ}
import scala.collection.Seq // Scala 2.13

// type class
trait AsMap[A, N <: Nat] {
  type Out
  def apply(list: List[A], selectors: Sized[Seq[A => String], N]): Out
}
object AsMap {
  type Aux[A, N <: Nat, Out0] = AsMap[A, N] {type Out = Out0}
  def instance[A, N <: Nat, Out0](f: (List[A], Sized[Seq[A => String], N]) => Out0): Aux[A, N, Out0] = new AsMap[A, N] {
    type Out = Out0
    override def apply(list: List[A], selectors: Sized[Seq[A => String], N]): Out = f(list, selectors)
  }

  implicit def zero[A]: Aux[A, _0, List[A]] = instance((l, _) => l)
  implicit def succ[A, N <: Nat](implicit
    asMap: AsMap[A, N]
  ): Aux[A, Succ[N], Map[String, asMap.Out]] =
    instance((l, sels) => l.groupBy(sels.head).view.mapValues(asMap(_, sels.tail)).toMap)
}

final class NestedStrMap[A, N <: Nat](list: List[A], selectors: (A => String)*){
  def asMap(implicit asMap: AsMap[A, N]): asMap.Out =
    asMap(list, Sized.wrap[Seq[A => String], N](selectors))
}
object NestedStrMap {
  def apply[N <: Nat] = new PartiallyApplied[N]
  class PartiallyApplied[N <: Nat] {
    def apply[A](list: List[A])(selectors: (A => String)*) = new NestedStrMap[A, N](list, selectors: _*)
  }
}

case class TestResult(name: String, testType: String, score: Int)

val testList: List[TestResult] = List(
  TestResult("A", "math", 75),
  TestResult("B", "math", 80),
  TestResult("B", "bio", 90),
  TestResult("C", "history", 50)
)
val nestedMap = NestedStrMap[_2](testList)(_.name, _.testType)
val someMap = nestedMap.asMap
someMap: Map[String, Map[String, List[TestResult]]]
//Map(A -> Map(math -> List(TestResult(A,math,75))), B -> Map(bio -> List(TestResult(B,bio,90)), math -> List(TestResult(B,math,80))), C -> Map(history -> List(TestResult(C,history,50))))
```

In Scala 2.13, instead of `import scala.collection.Seq` (i.e. if you want `Seq` to refer to `scala.Seq` aka `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`, which is standard for Scala 2.13, rather than to `scala.collection.Seq`) then you can define

```
implicit def immutableSeqAdditiveCollection[T]:
  shapeless.AdditiveCollection[collection.immutable.Seq[T]] = null
```

(Not sure why this implicit isn't defined, I guess it should.)

[Cats auto derived with Seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591709/cats-auto-derived-with-seq)

---

If you don't want to specify `N` manually, you can define a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox // libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value

object NestedStrMap {
  def apply[A](list: List[A])(selectors: (A => String)*): NestedStrMap[A, _ <: Nat] = macro applyImpl[A]

  def applyImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context)(list: c.Tree)(selectors: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val A = weakTypeOf[A]
    val len = selectors.length
    q"new NestedStrMap[$A, _root_.shapeless.nat.${TypeName(s"_$len")}]($list, ..$selectors)"
  }
}
```

```
// in a different subproject

val nestedMap = NestedStrMap(testList)(_.name, _.testType)
val someMap = nestedMap.asMap
someMap: Map[String, Map[String, List[TestResult]]]
//Map(A -> Map(math -> List(TestResult(A,math,75))), B -> Map(bio -> List(TestResult(B,bio,90)), math -> List(TestResult(B,math,80))), C -> Map(history -> List(TestResult(C,history,50))))
```

This will not work with

```
val sels = Seq[TestResult => String](_.name, _.testType)
val nestedMap = NestedStrMap(testList)(sels: _*)
```

because `sels` is a runtime value.

---

Alternatively to Shapeless, you can apply macros from the very beginning (with `foldRight`/`foldLeft` as you wanted)

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

final class NestedStrMap[A](list: List[A])(selectors: (A => String)*) {
  def asMap: Any = macro NestedStrMapMacro.asMapImpl[A]
}

object NestedStrMapMacro {
  def asMapImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val A = weakTypeOf[A]
    val ListA = weakTypeOf[List[A]]

    c.prefix.tree match {
      case q"new NestedStrMap[..$_]($list)(..$selectors)" =>
        val func = selectors.foldRight(q"_root_.scala.Predef.identity[$ListA]")((sel, acc) =>
          q"(_: $ListA).groupBy($sel).view.mapValues($acc).toMap"
        )
        q"$func.apply($list)"
    }
  }
}
```

```
// in a different subproject

val someMap = new NestedStrMap(testList)(_.name, _.testType).asMap
someMap: Map[String, Map[String, List[TestResult]]]
//Map(A -> Map(math -> List(TestResult(A,math,75))), B -> Map(bio -> List(TestResult(B,bio,90)), math -> List(TestResult(B,math,80))), C -> Map(history -> List(TestResult(C,history,50))))
```