# How maven shading works?

Tags: maven

In this Q&A post we'll try to answer the following questions -

1. What is shading in maven?
2. What is `maven-shade-plugin`, and what is used for ?
3. How to configure the `maven-shade-plugin` to achieve shading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. What is Shading ?

In the context of `maven`, shading is a process by which you can change the package name of certain dependencies your project relies on. One of the primary reasons to do this is to get around dependency version conflicts.

Think about this - Your project relies on a specific version of a dependency like `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind` - `v2.9.10`. You build a uber jar packaging the dependency in your service's artifact. Now, let's say the host on which you run your service provides a runtime environment which provides `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind` - `v2.6.7`.

We've got a problem. With two versions of the same library on the classpath, we're going to run into runtime errors and unpredictable behavior. For example, your code calls [`FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS` field in   `v2.9.10` of `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.9.10.8/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.java#L266), but that does not exist in [`com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind` - `v2.6.7`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/jackson-databind-2.6.7/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.java). So essentially, we've got two versions of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.java` class. The runtime is not gonna know which one to pull, and in such a situation most likely you'll see the following error during runtime -

```java
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS
```

And thats not good. When running your code in production, you want it to be predictable and under your control.

So, how do we get around this problem? Shading to the rescue. By shading we change the "fully qualified name" of the `DeserializationFeature.java` class - so instead of having two versions of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databing.DeserializationFeature.java` class, we'll have two **different** classes -

1. `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.java`
2. `shaded-base.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature.java`

where `shaded-base` is the prefix the `maven-shade-plugin` will apply to the `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind:2.9.10` artifact and all the classes within it. Let's see how it's actually done.

---

## 2. `Maven-Shade-Plugin`

Now that we're briefly familiar what shading is, and when to use it, let's drill a little bit into the `maven-shade-plugin` itself.

#### 2.a) Building an uber jar using `maven-shade-plugin`

Apart from shading, `maven-shade-plugin` can be used to build an uber jar, also known as "fat" jar. An uber jar is a jar in which you can package pretty much all the dependencies needed for your project.

Let's start with an example.
Check the [`<dependencies>` required for the `lake-tahoe` project.](https://github.com/AkshayRaj/lake-tahoe/blob/master/pom.xml#L20-L26)
By using the `maven-shade-plugin` we package the dependencies in the final artifact of the `lake-tahoe` project. You can do it yourself. Simply clone the repository, and run the following commands -

```
➜  lake-tahoe (master) mvn clean install
```

That's going to create `lake-tahoe-<version>-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the `target/` directory. Now, let's check if the `jackson` files are "packaged" in that artifact; We'll check for the `DeserializationFeature.java` file for the purposes of this post.

```
➜  lake-tahoe (master) jar tf target/lake-tahoe-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep DeserializationFeature
com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.class
```

Yup. We see that the `maven-shade-plugin` packages the dependencies of the project in the uber jar.

---

#### 2.b) Shading the dependencies.

We can use `<relocations>` element of the plugin to shade or "re-package" the dependencies. Check the [`truckee-river` project's `pom.xml` configuration](https://github.com/AkshayRaj/truckee-river/blob/master/pom.xml#L29-L72) to see how we accomplish that. Clone the repo and run the following commands -

```
truckee-river (master) mvn clean install
```

Let's inspect the contents of the `truckee-river`'s uber jar.

```
➜  truckee-river (master) ✗ jar tf target/truckee-river-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep DeserializationFeature
com/water/bodies/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.class
```

As you can see, all the classes in `com.fasterxml.jackson` have been "relocated" to `com.water.bodies.fasterxml.jackson`. So, that's shading.

---

#### 2.c) Using two versions of the same library with shading

Let's take a look at the `lake-pyramid` project. It pulls in `v2.6.7` of `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind` library, and it also pulls in `truckee-river` project. As we saw in #2.b section, `truckee-river` pulls in the `lake-tahoe` artifact, which in turn packages `v2.9.10` of `com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-databind`. However, `truckee-river` project shades the `com.fasterxml.jackson` and relocates it, in effect creating a new "fully qualified class".

Clone [`lake-pyramid`](https://github.com/AkshayRaj/lake-pyramid/blob/master/pom.xml#L27-L31) and you can see for yourself that both the shaded and the `v2.6.7` version are packaged in `lake-pyramid`'s final artifact.

```
➜  lake-pyramid (master) mvn clean install
// creates the `lake-pyramid-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
(base) ➜  lake-pyramid (master) jar tf target/lake-pyramid-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep DeserializationFeature
com/water/bodies/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.class
com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.class
```

---

So, that's pretty much it. Try the examples yourselves locally and you'd feel more comfortable.

**Trivia**: [The Truckee river is the sole outlet of Lake Tahoe and drains part of the high Sierra Nevada, emptying into Pyramid Lake in the Great Basin.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truckee_River)

Comment: I appreciate the efforts in your answer. A few points: `lake-tahoe (master)` and the like is part of the prompt, not part of the command. Usual characters like `$` or `>` in between would make this clearer. The bold arrows "➜" are too much. Code blocks are formatted easily recognizable already. "✗" is not a usual prompt character. If you'd use line continuation "\" one hasn't to scroll horizontally in the code blocks that much.