# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when running with console. Possibly Maven-related

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, command-line-interface

I have 2 java files:

```
package com.pokebot;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.exceptions.RateLimitedException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            JDA jdaBot = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken("my_token").buildBlocking();
            jdaBot.addEventListener(new Pokebot());
        } catch (LoginException e) {
    //            System.out.println("LoginException");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //            System.out.println("InterruptedException");
        } catch (RateLimitedException e) {
    //            System.out.println("RateLimitedException");
        }
    }

}
```

and:

```
package com.pokebot;

import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.MessageChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.User;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Pokebot extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {

        //Obtains properties of the received message
        Message objMsg = e.getMessage();
        MessageChannel objChannel = e.getChannel();
        User objUser = e.getAuthor();

        //Responds to any user who says "hello"
        if (objMsg.getContent().equals("hello")) {
            objChannel.sendMessage("Hello, " + objUser.getAsMention() +"!").queue();
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the application (the main class is App from 1st file) from Netbeans, I get only one notice:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```

but the application still works.
When I try to run it from command line:

```
java -jar target/pokebotapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

then I get an exception like this:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/core/exceptions/RateLimitedException`

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/core/
exceptions/RateLimitedException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.dv8tion.jda.core.exceptions.Rat
eLimitedException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

And the application does not even start.

I'm using Maven for this project. My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pokebot</groupId>
    <artifactId>pokebotapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <!--<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>-->
                            <mainClass>com.pokebot.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1_291</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    </project>
```

Before I try to run the project from the console, i run `maven compile`. I think it might possibly be the fault of the way I run the program, or the way I set up maven for this project. Is there anyone that knows what can be the problem?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

Comment: I added maven dependencies for `slf4j-api-1.7.5` and `slf4j-simple-1.7.5`, but still have the same problem, even after mvn clean install

Comment: did you update your project and check force updates snapshot and releases ?

Comment: I tried `mvn clean install -U` and Netbeans' `Download declared dependencies`... still the same. Is there any other way to update the project?

Comment: right click on your project->Maven->update project->check force update of snapshot and releases and then click ok

Comment: I don't have these options in NetBeans 8.2

Comment: Oh!! these steps are for eclipse, check how you could force to update the snapshot and releases in netbeans else delete the .m2 folder and update your maven once again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156999/discussion-between-lurker-and-lokesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because java doesn't know where to take this libs from. Few options:

1. Construct jar with all your dependencies included (so called uber-jar). This is done with maven shade plugin. Docs are available here: https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html
2. Do java -jar  -cp 
   Docs are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

First option is definitely better :) I guess there should be plenty of examples on stackoverflow how to configure maven-shade-plugin. Like this: 
[What is the maven-shade-plugin used for, and why would you want to relocate java packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java)

Comment: Just adding the maven plugin solved the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

### With gradle

This can be fixed by using the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) and building your jar with shadowJar instead. The jar will then be present in the build/libs directory with a name like example-1.0-all.jar

### With Maven

You need the [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) in your pom to add dependencies to your package task. You can see the shade plugin being applied in this [example pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/MinnDevelopment/5d8c5965043bbe5315d47b690cd7a4d9)

###### From https://jda.wiki/using-jda/troubleshooting/