# Program type already present com.squareup.okhttp.address when I tried to use grpc and cordova together

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, grpc, okhttp

Cordova.jar contains the package `com.squareup.okhttp` and a third party library I am using also contains this package as that library is using `grpc`. If I exclude okhttp package from the third party library, the application crashes as soon as the library functionality is initiated.How can I handle this conflict?

Comment: Take a look at jar shading. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by unzipping the cordova.jar file, removing the `com.squareup.okhttp` packages and then zipping it back to jar format. I feel there must be a better way to solve that problem.