How Maven handle two dependency depends on same jar but with different version
I have one case, I have two dependency from third party, let's say A and B.
And A and B all have dependency on C, but with different version.
let's say A depends on C 1.0, B depends on C 2.0.
And we can't ask A to work with C 2.0 and we don't have new A version which depends on C 2.0
Any idea we could handle such case? Even it is walkaround?

That's not a problem of Maven it's a problem of those artifacts A and B... Maven will use/delect the trantive dependency which is nearest to the project... if the same distant it will use which is given first on the pom file... But the problem is really related to A and B.. You should use a version of A which uses also C in Version 2... ..

Jason, take a look at the shade plugin which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620420/19972353

An underlying assumption in Maven is that a newer version of a given artifact can always replace an older one.
If for any reason that is not true (as has happened with Guice) you are basically on your own. Java does not work well with multiple versions of the same jar on the classpath, and even though work has been done on modularizing Java programs this clearly does not apply to your situation.
You will need versions of A and B that work with the same version of C. This is the long term solution.
If you cannot do that, you will have to create a layer that can make it look like it is that way.  Consider it mortgage on your technical debt.
