# I wish to exclude some class files from my jar. I am using maven-assembly-plugin. It still adds the files. I dont get any error

Tags: maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I dont get any error with this code. Just that the file that I want to exclude still gets added. I am using the maven plugin for eclipse

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>only</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/com/uiservices/controllers/*.*      </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `maven-assembly-plugin` doesn't work like that.

There what you want to do is override the configuration of the assembly descriptor `jar-with-dependencies` and that's not possible.

If what you want to do is create a jar similar to the one created by the assembly `jar-with-dependencies` but without some specific classes of your own project, you have to write your own assembly and call it in the `maven-assembly-plugin` like what follows.

Assembly in `src/assembly/jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml` :

```xml
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <!-- TODO: a jarjar format would be better -->
    <id>jar-with-dependencies-and-exclude-classes</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>com/uiservices/controllers/*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

This will create an assembly with no the dependencies unpacked and with your classes added except the ones excluded.

And then in your pom.xml :

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>only</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml</descriptor> 
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

But if what you need is your classical jar without excluded classes, you can exclude them in the `maven-jar-plugin` directly :

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/uiservices/controllers/*.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I had the same question/problem as the OP and this suggested solution solved my problem.

Comment: The last suggestion is the best: use the maven-jar-plugin, which is used by default, but can have its behiour overridden by declaring it in the build section as Fabien suggests

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with `maven-assembly-plugin`:

1. Project `beans-conversion` has files `application.properties`,
   `logback.xml`, and `logback.xsd`
2. Project `extract-conversion` has also files called `application.properties`, `logback.xml`, and `logback.xsd`
3. Requirement is `extract-conversion.jar` should include `beans-conversion.jar` content but `application.properties`, `logback.xml`, and `logback.xsd` of `extract-conversion.jar` should override the `beans-conversion.jar`.

**Solution:**

We solved this using `maven-shade-plugin` as below in extract-conversion's pom.xml.

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId> 
    <artifactId>beans-conversion</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
...
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
                <include>logback.xml</include>
                <include>logback.xsd</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.mycompany:beans-conversion</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>application.properties</exclude>
                                    <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>logback.xsd</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>                   
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: How we can exlude .class file here.   I have tried like this <exclude>org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.class</exclude>

Answer (score 1):

using maven-shade-plugin
ref: [Maven dependency: exclude one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086262/maven-dependency-exclude-one-class)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-jar-with-dependencies</finalName>
         <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer"> 
              <manifestEntries>
                 <Main-Class>com.taobao.arthas.core.Arthas</Main-Class>
              </manifestEntries>
             </transformer>
            </transformers>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:termd-core</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/services/io.termd.core.spi.ConfigProvider</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```