# Maven: Exclude Java File from Packaging

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java file which is executed during `maven:compile` phase to perform some file adjustments on each compilation.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>build-dump</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
      <mainClass>com.domain.internal.UpdateFile</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The thing is that this file is only for code maintenance and it is not needed in the final `Jar` package, so how can I exclude this file from being packaged into the final `Jar` while I keep it executing the maintenance code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One option is to have this file in another jar file(maven artifact) and use it as maven dependency, then you can specify scope compile for this dependency and it will not be included in the build.

Comment: Also, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023509/i-wish-to-exclude-some-class-files-from-my-jar-i-am-using-maven-assembly-plugin/30051240

Comment: First is this modifying the source code or the class files?