# Maven, exclude all classes but one under a package

Tags: maven

This may sound silly, but I really want to know if I can do that (by adding some 'magic' configuration in pom.xml).

Let's say, I have a project which has a bunch of packages, one of them, say  'com.foo.bar', has quite a few .java files, including one named 'Dummy.java'.

Now, when generating the jar file, I want to exclude all classes under com.foo.bar, except the 'Dummy'.

I tried regular expression in a  section, but no luck.

Is there an easy way to go? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With a "sledge hammer" (assuming Dummy.class not .java):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>com/foo/bar/Dummy.class</include>
    </includes>
    <!-- alternatively(!) excludes/exclude* -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

... or with a "Swiss army knife": [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) ... ^^!"%/"))

> ...
>
> To use the Assembly Plugin in Maven, you simply need to:
>
> 1. [choose](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin//descriptor-refs.html#) or [write](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin//assembly.html) the assembly descriptor to use,
> 2. [configure](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin//usage.html) the Assembly Plugin in your project's pom.xml,
> 3. and
>      run "mvn assembly:single" on your project.
>      ...

with an assembly [descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin//assembly.html) like:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
   <id>dummy-only</id>
   <formats>
     <format>jar</format>
   </formats>
   <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
   <fileSets>
     <fileSet>
     <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
     <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
     <includes>
       <include>com/foo/bar/Dummy.class</exclude>
     </includes>
   </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

see also: [I wish to exclude some class files from my jar. I am using maven-assembly-plugin. It still adds the files. I dont get any error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30023509/592355)

Comment: for the 'sledge hammer', all other packages are also removed from jar, this is not what I want.

Comment: ...you con combine multiple `<include/>`s ..with wildcards.

Comment: :) that doesn't sound like a good way, since I have quite a few packages

Comment: so when there is no "easy way" (with wildcards), then there is no "easy way" at all! :), but experiment a little, research the doc of these "includes/excludes", and maybe you find a suitable solution.

Comment: a big fat 'NO WAY' is good enough, thank you. I can actually put that Dummy class in a separate package then use 'exclude'. I'm just curious to know if there's any magic trick in maven, good to know there's no easy way to go.