# How to find in what artifact will Maven place a given class

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to find from Maven in what artifact will a given class be placed?

For some context of what I'm doing: I have a class in a Maven project that I was expecting to be present in an artifact but when I try to use that artifact in another project it doesn't compile because it doesn't find the class.
I can do a search in the jar files and find where the class file is. But Maven has this information already from the configuration of the first project.

So my question is if there is any **maven command or plugin** that could tell me in what artifact a given class is going to be added

Comment: I do not really understand the problem. You build an artifact from Maven project. Then the classes from that project go to that artifact.

Comment: The problem IMO is less important, the question can be pure theoretical. But there can be factors complicating things: the class can go in the jar or the test-jar artifact, it can be excluded from the artifact [one way or another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023509/i-wish-to-exclude-some-class-files-from-my-jar-i-am-using-maven-assembly-plugin) etc

Comment: Possibly the class is loaded from multiple jars. Welcome to jar hell.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But usually, everything under `src/main/java` is compiled then goes to the JAR or WAR that is generated, following the package structure inside `src/main/java`.

Comment: I am not sure about this. Maven has this information inside the poms... Just like the information about the dependency tree and this one can be displayed... Thanks, anyway

Comment: Sure, you can probably write a Maven plugin that tries to track this.