# Resolving same classes defined in different dependencies

Tags: maven

I'm running into a strange issue where I have two dependencies in my Maven file that both define `BasicLineFormatter.class`. The issue that I am running into is that one of my dependencies obviously uses a different version that the code is expecting and it throws and error.

How can I tell Maven that I want to use my standard `http-core` dependency for this class rather than the one that is causing an issue.

```
RESOURCE LOCATION: jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/tika-app-1.10.jar!/org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.class
```

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<groupId>xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>xxx</name>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>-->
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My code is getting the `BasicLineFormatter` class from the Tika dependency which is causing the issue. I want it to be coming from my defined `http-core` which is the correct version. It also seems to be ignoring the ordering the dependencies in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use - Shade Plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

Reference - [Maven dependency: exclude one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086262/maven-dependency-exclude-one-class)