# How to resolve this conflicting of two beans with same name in maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Suppose i have a Maven Project A and Project B, and project B i am adding it as as a jar in Project A when i try to run Project A it gives me the error "**bean name "xyz" conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class**"

So anyone has solution to this to ignore the bean "xyz" of Project B and run only "xyz" bean of Project A or is there any annotation or something like that?

Comment: Having that situation is kind of a code-smell. Perhaps it is time to look into refactoring?

Comment: Using @Lazy on bean "xyz" of Project B could be an approach?

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen actually i have created maven project with jersey archetype so both project A and B contains same Jersey Configuration file,..its default created class. that's why. now can u suggest me something which can work?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [@Primary](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation on the bean defenition on the configuration class

```
@Bean(name = "beanOnA")
@Primary
public YourInterface yourBeanOnProjectA(){
    return new YourClass("Bean on Project A");
}
```

While autowiring the bean specify the bean name using qualifier annotation.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("beanOnA")
YourInterface yourInterface;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Qualifier annotation to achieve this.

```
@Qualifier("ProjectA")

or

@Qualifier("complete.package.ProjectA")
```

Comment: This only helps if you are able to edit the code. What if it is external dependensies

Answer (score -2):

You can edit pom file for B to exclude the class file while packing [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920920/maven-excluding-java-files-in-compilation)

Edit pom file A using shade plugin to exclude the class file from B, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167118/exclude-classes-from-a-dependency-in-maven)