# Jar dependency in eclipse - same class in 2 external jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, dependencies

i have a jar dependency problem and dont know how to solve it.

The class HttpClientBuilder is in two external jars in my referenced libraries. But in the one eclipse picks, a method is missing. I think because this jars has all its dependend libraries inside of it and this httpclient is outdated.

Is it somehow possible to tell eclipse which external jar should be picked for the HttpClientBuilder class?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setSSLHostnameVerifier(Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.<init>(DefaultAbsSender.java:63)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.<init>(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:35)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.<init>(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:31)
    at minerbot.CommandHandler.<init>(CommandHandler.java:9)
    at minerbot.Main$CommandThread.run(Main.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not using a software project management and comprehension tool like maven, ant etc then you should use it as it helps in managing dependencies by excluding the ones that are not required by your project.

Basically, you can exclude the dependencies jars that are not required by your project so that you do not get unnecessary transitive dependencies.

If you would like to exclude only classes from certain jars then here is one option to do it.

[Exclude classes from a dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167118/exclude-classes-from-a-dependency-in-maven)

Here is example to exclude unnecessary dependency jars (maven official website) ...

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Maven Eclipse plugin installation:

- Open Eclipse IDE & Click Help - Install New Software
- Click add button and on pop up fill up name as "M2Eclipse" and location as  "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" or http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.0
- Click OK and wait for installation to complete

Confirm Eclipse Settings:

- Open Window - Preferences
- Check if Maven is listed in left panel and check the settings in installations
- Click on an existing project and right click to select Configure -> Convert to Maven Project

Comment: Okay i installed maven but dont understand how to use it.. which values do i need to add to the pom.xml if i want to exclude "org.apache.http.impl.client" from the external jar "telegrambots-3.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

Comment: Do you need any other class from telegrambots-3.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar and if its a transitive dependency then then you can exclude it altogether from the dependency where it is being pulled form. If you need other classes from that jar then try putting this jar just below the other jar from which you need the class to be used.

Comment: Yes i need all other classes. Only this org.apache.http.impl.client . I added   </build>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.pengrad</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-telegram-bot-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
</project> so it should fit ... now eclipse says it doesnt find the classes. I already selected "Update Project" in Eclipse but it doesnt help...

Comment: If eclipse can't find classes, it means the maven repo is not set correctly. Check Maven settings in eclipse and make sure that the maven repo has the jars inside the folders (package name).